# Dynamically change field of Django admin inline form

Tags: python, django, admin

I want to dynamically change a `CharField` to a `ChoiceField`, because I want the value to be selected from a list of possibilities that is determined by the current request.

In a `ModelAdmin` I can do that with `get_form()`, and just say:

```
form.base_fields[field_name] = forms.ChoiceField(...)
```

but how can I do the same for an `InlineModelAdmin` `(TabularInline)`?
I stepped a bit through `get_formset()` and `get_fieldsets()` but can't find the right spot for hooking in.

Comment: Note the [docs warn against modifying `base_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form): *"Beware not to alter the base_fields attribute ..."* However, I wonder if this extends to the `ModelFormMetaClass` returned by `get_form()` (or `FormSet.form`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `get_formsets` method you can use like `get_form` for the inlines. This is the default version from [`django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.1/django/contrib/admin/options.py):

```
def get_formsets(self, request, obj=None):
    for inline in self.inline_instances:
        yield inline.get_formset(request, obj)
```

Comment: Thanks! "formset = inline.get_formset(request, obj)" followed by "form = formset.form" and then I was able to proceed as in the ModelAdmin.

Comment: warning seen on django code: "ModelAdmin.get_formsets() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9. Use ModelAdmin.get_formsets_with_inlines() instead"

Comment: Just to be clear, the get_formsets will be a method of the inline class, right? For some reason get_formsets is not being called here =/

Answer (score -1):

You can give a form class to the InlineModelAdmin:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options

or for dynamic stuff you can override the get_form method:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L431

Comment: The form is not statically changed, that's determined at runtime. get_form() is not called in InlineModelAdmin.